# convergence proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $k$ be a natural number. If sequence $b_n$ is obtained by deleting the first $k$ members of the sequence $a_n$, then $b_n$ is convergent if and only if $a_n$ is convergent.

I know that if $a_n$ is convergent then there exist some $N$ and $L$ such that for all $n>N$,
$|a_n -L|< \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$. What do I do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition $b_n=a_{n+k}$ for all $n$.

Hence $n > N-k$ implies $|b_n-L|=|a_{n+k}-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Perhaps there is some confusion about the "for all $\epsilon>0$".  It should be "for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ implies $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$."  Informally, this means that if someone gives us $\epsilon$, we can find an $N$.  (Not that there is an $N$ that works for all $\epsilon$, which the phrasing in the question suggests.)

Comment: Formally, N is not a function of $\epsilon$. it's just relative to it.

Comment: @I'mtoo Formally, you can construct an explicit "choice function" $N(\epsilon)$, because for all $\epsilon$, at least one such $N$ exists which meets the requirement, so you can choose an arbitrary $N$ from the set of valid $N$ for each $\epsilon$ and get a function.

Comment: @AlexR: If you believe in Axiom of Choice!! (just kidding :) )

Answer (score 0):

### Part 1

Let $N(\epsilon)$ be such, that
$$|a_n - L| < \epsilon \qquad \forall\ n > N(\epsilon)$$
This exists if $(a_n)_n$ converges. Then let
$$M(\epsilon) := N(\epsilon) - k$$
now for $m < M(\epsilon)$ we have
$$|b_m - L| = |a_{m+k} - L| \stackrel{m < M(\epsilon) = N(\epsilon) - k}{<} \epsilon$$
So given $\epsilon > 0$ we can find $M(\epsilon)$, such that
$$|b_m - L| < \epsilon \qquad \forall\ m > M(\epsilon)$$
So $(a_n)_n \to L \Rightarrow (b_n)_n \to L$

### Part 2

Let $(a_n)$ diverge. Then $\forall\ \epsilon > 0, N\in\mathbb{N}, L\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $n = n(\epsilon, N, L) > N$ with
$$|a_n - L| \geq \epsilon$$
Now given $\epsilon, M, L$ and chose
$$m = m(\epsilon, M, L) := n(\epsilon, M-k, L)$$
then
$$|b_m - L| = |a_{m+k} - L| \stackrel{m+k > M-k}{\geq} \epsilon$$
So $(a_n)_n \not\to L \forall\ L\in\mathbb R \Rightarrow (b_n)_n \not\to L \forall\ L\in\mathbb R$.

q.e.d.

Comment: Note, that the choice of $n=n(\epsilon, N, L)$ is not guaranteed to be unique, but we can construct a "function" $n(\epsilon, N, L)$ which will meet the requirements for all input parameters.